# Best way to design microservice architecture when there is a dependency between databases?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

We are planning to migrate our product to micro service architecture using spring boot. 
I have few doubts/concerns for "each service should have separate database".
If I created separate database for each service, then how to handle the table dependency.

For example: I have 2 micro services.

**1. Customer Service:** it has "customer" table (fields: customerId, customerName, etc...)

**2. Order Service:** it has "order" table (fields: orderId, orderName, customerId, etc...)

**Note:** for simplicity I mentioned only 1 table in each service here.

When I tried to access the order details based on orderId, I may want to retrieve the details of customer also.

In this case, I have two options in my mind:

1. Using RestTemplate call the "customer service" GET of customerById API and fetch the required details and set it in the response of OrderDetails.
2. Create customer table also in Order Service and using database tool replicate the data from customer service to order service's customer table. i.e., any changes done to customer table in customer service database will reflect on order service's customer table.
   So, I can easily fetch relevant data from order service itself.

Please suggest which one is preferable. If both doesn't make sense, please suggest best way to handle this.

Thanks.

Comment: Option 1 is the right way

Comment: @pvpkiran thanks. Is there any other way to handle ?

Comment: Duplicate the data... Why would an update to the customer need to update existing orders? Those are probably already processed and delivered. You don't want to change the delivery address etc. on existing orders.

Comment: @M.Deinum for example only I mentioned these table. I just need the best way to handle table dependencies. i.e., Using inter-communication between the services OR duplicating/replicating the master/join table in all dependent services. Please suggest.

Comment: I marked the question as primarily opinion based. If you want to follow microservices you should duplicate the data, how you obtain that data can be a call, could be in an event. It depends on your general application architecture.

Comment: @M.Deinum just to make sure, you mean 2nd option is preferable for micro services architecture ?

Comment: Duplicating the data is a very good option, but there are different ways to do this. Also, another service that will aggregate data from two services is reasonable. You _probably_ shouldn't couple Order to Customer though. Emphasis on probably.